# Plotting cities in a specific state using Google Geochart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying plot markers in a specific city using google Geochart when the region is set to that state (so just that state is displayed, not the entire US). I can get the specific state to plot, but when I try to add a marker nothing displays.

Nothing displays when I try to put markers on cities

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['geochart']});

function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',  'Population', 'Area'],
    ['Los Angeles',     2761477,    1285.31]
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
   geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: 'US-CA', resolution: 'provinces'});
}


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I'm able to get it to plot when I just do it by state. So, swapping out the functions for this, it works just fine

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
  data.addRow(['US-CA', 1000]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: 'US-CA', resolution: 'provinces'});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Province level maps (e.g., US-CA) is not supported by GeoMaps. Works in GeoChart.  There is a feature request on the [Google Visualization API bug reports and feature requests](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=279).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to plot states, but I can't seem to plot markers for cities now. I updated my code above. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to enable dataMode: 'Markers' in options

Comment: It is displayMode:'markers', it took me some time to figure out ;)